# The type 'T' must be convertible in order to use it as parameter 'T' in the generic type or method

Tags: c#, generics

I have these two main classes. First the FSMSystem class:

```
public class FSMSystem<T> : MonoBehaviour where T : FSMSystem<T>
{
    private T m_Owner = default(T);

    protected FSMState<T> currentState;

    private Dictionary<int, FSMState<T>> m_states;

    public FSMSystem(T owner)
    {
        m_Owner = GameObject.FindObjectOfType(typeof(T)) as T; //owner;
        m_states = new Dictionary<int, FSMState<T>>();
    }

    protected void AddState( FSMState<T> state )
    {
        m_states.Add( state.GetStateID(), state );
    }
}
```

And the second class, FSMState:

```
public abstract class FSMState<T>
{   
    public abstract int GetStateID();

    public abstract void OnEnter (FSMSystem<T> fsm, FSMState<T> prevState);
    public abstract void OnUpdate (FSMSystem<T> fsm);
    public abstract void OnExit (FSMSystem<T> fsm, FSMState<T> nextState);
}
```

It leads to the following error:

> error CS0309: The type '`T`' must be convertible to '`FSMSystem<T>`' in
>   order to use it as parameter '`T`' in the generic type or method
>   '`FSMSystem<T>`'

Can someone tell me how to resolve this? I see many other posts similar to this one but I'm not seeing the relationship.

Comment: which code leads to this error?

Comment: I agree, why don't you remove the constraint all together? The code seems to compile fine without it.

Comment: @J.Steen That could be an (the) answer, methinks.

Comment: @Onots While I'm usually disinclined to give answers that are (albeit cryptically) explained by the compiler errors, I'll give it a crack.

Comment: @J.Steen - in C++, it's called the Curiously Recurring Template Pattern. Eric Lippert has a blog post about it called [Curiouser and curiouser](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2011/02/03/curiouser-and-curiouser.aspx) where he points out that it's a flawed approach in C# (but it's perfectly compilable)

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever Thank you for a name to put to the construct. I agree it's flawed, I agree the code - as it stands - can be compiled, but can it actually **be used** in C#? Can you instantiate a class of type `FSMSystem<T>`?

Comment: Consider `class MyFSM : FSMSystem<MyFSM>{}` You can't directly instantiate a `FSMSystem<T>`, but you can instantiate a class that *derives* from it.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever D'oh. I've even USED that construct. It was so long ago that I completely forgot.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The `T` of `FSMState` must also be constrained, otherwise it cannot be used as the `T` of `FSMSystem` - which has constraints placed on it (`T : FSMSystem<T>`).

If you would have provided the line number of the compiler error, I suspect it would point to the methods `OnEnter`, etc.

Comment: the errors occurred these lines.

public abstract void OnEnter (FSMSystem<T> fsm, FSMState<T> prevState);
    public abstract void OnUpdate (FSMSystem<T> fsm);
    public abstract void OnExit (FSMSystem<T> fsm, FSMState<T> nextState);

Comment: This was helpful for me, I put the constraint right after the class name instead of the interfaces

Answer (score 0):

It's big help to me. thank you all. I resolved the problem. I misunderstood about 'where' syntax.

Here is the revised version that works.

```
public class FSMSystem<T> : MonoBehaviour where T : FSMSystem<T>
{
    private T m_Owner = default(T);

    protected FSMState<T> currentState;

    private Dictionary<int, FSMState<T>> m_states;

    public FSMSystem()
    {
        m_Owner = this as T;
        m_states = new Dictionary<int, FSMState<T>>();
    }

    protected void AddState( FSMState<T> state )
    {
        m_states.Add( state.GetStateID(), state );
    }
}


public abstract class FSMState<T> where T : FSMSystem<T>
{
    public abstract int GetStateID();

    public abstract void OnEnter (T fsm, FSMState<T> prevState);
    public abstract void OnUpdate (T fsm);
    public abstract void OnExit (T fsm, FSMState<T> nextState);
}
```