# The type ... must be convertible to ... in order to use it as parameter 'T' in the generic method

Tags: c#, .net

Below I will describe my problem with a short sample code:

```cs
// model interface and implmentation
public interface IModel { }

public class Model : IModel{}

// generic interface which constraint T from IModel
public interface IBaseInterface<T> where T:IModel{ }

public interface IDerivedInterface : IBaseInterface<Model>{}


public class Test
{
    void FuncTest<T>() where T:IBaseInterface<IModel>
    {
        
    }

    void CallFunc()
    {
        // error: ... see below
        FuncTest<IDerivedInterface>();
    }
}
```

error info is :`The type 'IDerivedClass' must be convertible to 'IBaseClass<IDerivedClass>' in order to use it as parameter  'T' in the generic method 'void Test.FuncTest<T>()'`

my understanding is: `Model` implements the `IModel` interface, and `IDerivedInterface` implements the `IBaseInterface` interface,then `IDerivedInterface` should be able to be converted to `IBaseInterface<IModel>` type,but compiler tells me it cannot convert.

I have read related questions on stackoverflow such as：

1. [The type must be convertible in order to use it as parameter in the generic class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37926318/the-type-must-be-convertible-in-order-to-use-it-as-parameter-in-the-generic-clas)
2. [error CS0309: The type ... must be convertible to ... in order to use it as parameter in the generic type or method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38054507/error-cs0309-the-type-must-be-convertible-to-in-order-to-use-it-as-para)
3. [The type 'TNestedInterface' must be convertible to 'INestedInterfaceTest' in order to use it as parameter 'TNestedInterface'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19234353/the-type-tnestedinterface-must-be-convertible-to-inestedinterfacetest-in-ord)
4. [Can not use parameter in generic class, because is not convertible to base class, although all constraints seem to be good](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69897947/can-not-use-parameter-in-generic-class-because-is-not-convertible-to-base-class)
5. [The type 'T' must be convertible in order to use it as parameter 'T' in the generic type or method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16685825/the-type-t-must-be-convertible-in-order-to-use-it-as-parameter-t-in-the-gene)

I guess the reason may be related to covariance and inversion, ut the answer to the question in the link above doesn't make me understand the problem, can anyone give me a clear explanation?

[image]
error info screenshot

1. ide: rider 2022.2 version
2. .Net version: .Net 6

Comment: My god....you created a method called `Func`. I thought you were using [Func](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.func-1?view=net-7.0). That's confusing. I suggest you choose a different name.

Comment: @ProgrammingLlama Still the same error after I changed the function name to `FuncTest`，error screenshot I added in my answer below

Comment: Why did you add an answer if it doesn't answer your question? And I didn't say it would resolve your question. I said it would make your question less confusing.

Comment: Does [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4653199/3181933) answer your question? Or perhaps [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4038168/3181933) or [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1817341/3181933)? I'm sure how `IList<IModel>` in these questions is basically identical to `IBaseInterface<IModel>` in your question.

Comment: @ProgrammingLlama thx, i think I've figured out why, the solution is modified this line `public interface IBaseInterface<out T> where T:IModel{ }` (add `out` symbol)